# Theming main menu with block--menu.tpl.php not working

Tags: routes, blocks, theming

My template file `block--menu.tpl.php` is not catching my main menu block. It works for custom menus. Am I missing something on this? I don't have any other specific block overrides.

I'm running Drupal v7.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

main-menu comes from system module, so it should be **block--system--main-menu.tpl.php**

Cheers